# jQuery callback not working for load function, not detecting hover events

Tags: jquery

Using wordpress with atahualpa theme, and I have hyperlinks that reference a simple javascript, that loads the output of a php file into a div. This part works fine.

```
<a href="javascript:loadCategory(19,1);">a link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#categoryposts").load("http://www.mysite.com/myphp.php?cat="+catid+"&paged="+pagedid+"", "", 
      function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if(textStatus == 'error') {
            jQuery('#categoryposts').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
        }
      }
  );
  }
</script>
```

But I want to have fun with images ([sliding boxgrid](http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/)) that are loaded into div "#categoryposts", however this is where I hit a wall. My php outputs divs with the proper classes but I cannot get any hover response from jQuery at all.  I suspect it is related somehow to the way that the DOM loads but I can't figure it out.  For example, when I try adding the good stuff as a callback function, as below, I do see alert1, but I never get alert2, and the hover function doesn't work.

```
         function loadCategory(catid,pagedid) {

jQuery("#categoryposts").load("http://www.mysite.com/myphp.php?cat="+catid+"&paged="+pagedid+"", function()
 {  
   alert('alert1');
   jQuery('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){ 
       alert('alert2');
       jQuery(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'160px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
       }, function(){
        jQuery(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'220px'},{queue:false,duration:160}); }
  )}, 
      function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if(textStatus == 'error') {
            jQuery('#categoryposts').html('<p>There was an error making the AJAX request</p>');
        }
      }
  );

 }
```

I've spent an entire day trying to hack through this, trying all sorts of things, but hitting a wall. Hoping a jQuery guru out there can lend a hand.

Edit: cleaned up code formatting

Comment: You can format the code example by making sure each line is indented by at least 4 characters. Here's the section on formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

The callback for load() may be executing after the data is retrieved, but before it is appended to the DOM. After alert('alert1') try adding something like this:

```
alert(jQuery('.boxgrid.caption').length);
```

That should tell you if that collection exists at that point or not.

Another possibility would be to use the "live()" function, instead of attempting to append those event handlers in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your selector is wrong. Have you tried something like

alert($('.boxgrid.caption').length) to see if it returns a nonzero value?

Comment: OMG what an embarassing error.  I can't believe I blew an entire day hunting this down.  The problem was a typo in the classname given to my div in the HTML.  The hover function was not triggering because it didn't exist, due to the typo.  Thank you RussellUresti and axel_c!!!  Your advice about the alert got me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Quick question before I set this to Solved.  I did discover the live function while hunting this down, and wonder... should I be using it instead of a callback?  The callback now seems to work, but I should I be using live?  Is it just a personal preference, or is there some fundamental reason to use live?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the hover function using jQuery's 'live' method? Rather than binding hover within the load callback, you could bind it separately using something like this:

```
$(".boxgrid.caption").live('hover', function(){
    //your hover function
});
```

This allows for dynamic binding, even when the elements are loaded after the fact.